# Choose one of three kind of bikes (Mountain Bikes, Touring Bikes, and Road Bikes) using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

When I build a web app using MVC 4, it has three kind of bikes ("Mountain Bikes", "Touring Bikes", and "Road Bikes").

When one clicks on "Mountain Bikes" I want to get all models of "Mountain Bikes" and so on. What should I do to fix my code?

```
var listId = db.ProductSubcategories
               .Where(pc => pc.ProductSubcategoryID == 1 || pc.ProductSubcategoryID == 2 || pc.ProductSubcategoryID == 3)
               .Select(pc => pc.ProductSubcategoryID);
```

Comment: can you provide your models ? Maybe Product and productSubCategory ?

Comment: Can you explain how the example LINQ you provided doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: @TheGreatCO: That LINQ I provided list all of models in three kind of bikes, not one of them.

Comment: @Selman22 **Product** table: Name: Mountain-500 Black, 52 **ProductSubcategories** table: NameofBike: Mountain Bikes matched each other with **ProductSubcategoryID** = 2

Comment: Which `ProductSubcategoryID` relates to which type of bike?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question properly you need to actually know what the SubcategoryId is for the bike you are referring to e.g.

```
string selectedBike = "Mountain Bike";
var selectedBikeSubCategory = db.ProductSubcategories.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == selectedBike); // Assuming you have a name for sub categories
if (selectedBikeSubCategory != null)
{
    var allMountainBikes = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductSubcategoryID == selectedBikeSubCategoryId.ID); // will give you all products matching the selected sub category bike type
}
```

Comment: It will make 2 separate queries to the database.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yes indeed, at this stage there was nothing in the question stating that only a single query was required.  If the app is designed correctly then the subcategoryid(s) are already evaluated and only the second query would be needed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var criteria = new string[] {"1","2","3"};
var listId = from x in db.ProductSubcategories where criteria.Contains(x.ProductSubcategoryID);
```

Contains method is considered more readable

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?